# How to save crop image with alpha value

Tags: export, image

I have an image with alpha channel. I want to take a crop and save it with alpha channel. When I save it manually using the "save Image As" tools, I get an RGB image without channel value!

[image]

Comment: I think we can use Export[] instead

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can use Export["imagename.png", , Background -> None].